# How to synchronize files across partitions larger than 2TB in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sync

Every software I've tried (robocopy, MS SyncToy, PureSync, Allway Sync, Supercopier2) all exhibit strange behavior and fail during a full sync. Some symptoms of non-working apps include: locking up while not actually doing anything (e.g. stuck on "Analyzing...100%" after several hours), reporting that everything ran successfully (without anything actually having happened), or just refusing to run entirely.

Due to these results I've become somewhat hesitant to keep testing software until something works, primarily for fear that perhaps instead of not doing anything, one tool will instead delete my data.

Are there any (preferably free) apps to sync directories that work with 3TB (and larger) partitions in Windows 7 x64?

Comment: I wonder if CopyHandler still exists... And if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync will do this.  On Windows platforms you can use [Delta Copy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which is a "windows friendly wrapper" for rsync.

Or, if you wanted to avoid potentially permissions problems you could try [Syncrify](http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm).

Comment: Seems a bit overboard? Both require server and client software.

Comment: I haven't tried the windows versions, but Rsync (which they're based on) is very easy to use, once you've tried a few examples and understand the commands.

Comment: @glenneroo - also, on Linux a lot of stuff is client server.  Playing mp3s, the X window system, etc.  So it's not as overboard as it sounds.